# How to scan barcode and store data into a database

Tags: database

we need to provide a web application to enable the user to be able to scan barcodes and feed that data into the system, preferably into a database for further processing. The user  shall be scanning about 10,000 documents a day (maybe one or even two operators). The documents themselves shall NOT be scanned, only the barcode that is present on each of them.
This barcode value then needs to be pushed into a database. I was thinking of using WP for the application, so finding a suitable method would be great. Thanks